# How to let Handbrake recognize a VIDEO_TS folder?

Tags: handbrake

My Kung Fu Panda DVD movie has become scratched. It contains the following files:

```
BUP files:

 - VIDEO_TS.BUP *
 - VTS_01_0.BUP *
 - VTS_02_0.BUP
 - VTS_03_0.BUP

IFO files:

 - VIDEO_TS.IFO *
 - VTS_01_0.IFO *
 - VTS_02_0.IFO
 - VTS_03_0.IFO

VOB files:

 - VTS_01_0.VOB *
 - VTS_01_1.VOB *
 - VTS_01_2.VOB *
 - VTS_01_3.VOB *
 - VTS_01_4.VOB *
 - VTS_01_5.VOB *
 - VTS_02_1.VOB
 - VTS_03_1.VOB
```

Filenames with an asterisk can be copied without any problems; most of the other files cannot be copied. I tried CDCheck and DVDDecrypter. Since title 1 is the main movie and related files can be copied, I copied them to a folder and can run the movie from the folder using VLC Media Player.

However, I'd like to convert the DVD movie using Handbrake 0.9.4. When I choose the folder that contains the asterisk-marked files in Handbrake interface (`Source > DVD/VIDEO_TS Folder`), Handbrake scans the folder and shows the following error message:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
No Title(s) found. 

Your Source may be copy protected, badly mastered
or in a format which HandBrake does not support. 
Please refer to the Documentation and FAQ (see Help Menu).
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Clearly there is a title which Handbrake cannot find. If I could copy all files in a folder, Handbrake would not give this message. But all files cannot be copied even using CDCheck or DVDDecrypter. Are there any hacks to fool Handbrake into recognize the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this [link](http://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6698&p=38088&hilit=libdvdcss#p38088) handbrake is libdvdcss free in specific versions and therefore can't process protected dvds. since most dvds you can buy are protected i'm pretty sure that's your problem.

the linked text furthermore claims that handbrake automatically utilizes vlc for this job if installed.

Comment: Even though one's mother might tell a person not to believe wild claims, sometimes they are, in fact correct. As is the one you linked.

Comment: Hi again, I looked at the link and looked at the options of Handbrake 0.9.4. I have VLC Media Player installed. But still unsure about how to utilize libdvdcss. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the link claims that handbrake automatically uses libdvdcss from vlc and you don't have to do anything than install vlc and handbrake and use handbrake.

Comment: hm, i just saw on their original website http://handbrake.fr/ that they only mention this on mac and linux. maybe it isn't supported under windows. but i don't think they left out windows with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rename the VIDEO_TS folder, otherwise Handbrake would not recognize files in it.